# Permission Denied | Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

Recently got Permission Denied, and didn't see a solution on this site.

```
$ docker ps -a
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Comment: Run all docker commands with sudo.

Comment: Noted for future. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To avoid these permission issues run the following command

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

[Source](https://onecompiler.com/posts/3uetmsjpc/fixing-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket)

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                        PORTS                                       NAMES
115682275acc  ...
```